# Export hidden characters from MySQL-Database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL-Database (data from OTRS) and a PHP-script that reads data from this database and emails this data to a specific address. That actually works.

My problem is, that the stored data has "hidden" characters like linebreaks etc. that are just exported as "blank" and not as new line.

How does MySQL store this data and how to make it appear in a normal "echo"-command in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL normally doesn't change what it stores. However, linebreaks are usually stored, by programs like OTRS, as the ASCII character 13.

If you echo something with PHP to a browser you should write HTML. A linebreak in HTML is `<br>`. So you can do this to texts:

```
$html = str_replace("\n",'<br>',$text);
```

Then echo it and linebreaks will be visible in your browser.